# Latex Double subscript with $ with text and equation in the same line

Tags: equations, text

[image][image: I want to print text and equation like this in the image in latex but I am getting double script error with $.]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1brtQ.png): How to combine text and equation in a paragraph in latex?

Comment: `$i$ can be equal to $j$. ... \textit{Domino tiles} $\{P_{8(i-1)+1}, P_{8(i-1+2}, \ldots, P_{8i}\}$ [2] from the permutation, ...`

Comment: Consider reading some starter documentation on (La)TeX. Your question is fundamental to using (La)TeX, so you need some foundation...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$`...`$` or `\(`...`\)` to set inline math as part of paragraph text. I prefer the former:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
$i$ can be equal to~$j$. The total number of pips~$p$ of a \emph{Domino
tile} is defined as $p(S_{ij}) = i + j$ \cite{domino}. The \emph{game} begins by setting
a constant permutation of the \emph{Domino tiles} ($P_{ij} = \pi(S_{ij})$)
that permits player~$i$ to take seven random \emph{Domino tiles}
$\{ P_{8(i-1)+1}, P_{8(i-1)+2}, \ldots, P_{8i} \}$ \cite{domino} from the permutation, at

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{abc} First reference.
  \bibitem{domino} Second reference.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```